# Samsung SSD & BIOS possible firmware clash?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, bios, firmware

I'll try to make this mystery as simple as possible in the following way:

***My components***:

- **Motherboard**: Asus P8Z77-V
- **SSD**: Kingston 120GB (ssdNOW 300)
- **HDD**: Seagate BarraCuda 1TB
- **CPU**: Intel® Core™ i7-3770
- **RAM**: Kingston 16GB (8x2) 1600MHZ DDR3
- **OS**: Linux Mint 21.1

**Recently bought**: 870 EVO SATA 2.5" SSD 250GB

**Intention**: To replace Kingston SSD with a Samsung SSD for greater storage capacity.

**The problem**:
When Samsung SSD and Seagate HDD are both connected at the same time, almost a clash-like behaviour occurs with the system.

**Explanation**:
When I installed new Samsung SSD without plugging in the HDD, the system installed just fine and worked as expected, it even installed faster than on the old Kingston SSD. BUT when I've plugged in the HDD the system immediately behaved like it got scrambled, icons dissapeared and I couldn't do anything. I tested Windows 10 then, of course, I got BSOD. Then I plugged in BOTH Samsung SSD and Seagate HDD started a fresh install but Samsung SSD wasn't on the list in the install options on Linux Mint. On Windows it said that it can't be installed on a non GPT partition. I disabled CSM options in BIOS but still the same issue.
I was able to install **Pop!_OS** with both drives connected but then the boot process takes **significantly longer time** and I was denied access to HDD and had to manually grant it. Wasn't smooth experience and wasn't really usable that way.
I have returned old Kingston SSD and PC works without any issues.

I've tried swapping SATA cables, changing power cables, still the same.

My thought is that maybe my ASUS motherboard doesn't fully support Samsung SSD drive when connected with another internal HDD, but does work fine with Kingston one. There are no more BIOS updates for this MOBO, last one was 2013.

I just don't understand it. Seems like wasted money on Samsung SSD in this case.

Any ideas? Is it maybe Samsung SSD Firmware not being recognized by the BIOS or something else? I have no other option but to buy another Kingston 240 GB SSD if I want more storage for the main system.

Comment: Probably nothing to do with having two drives connected reagardless of what they are. Very likely related to what was installed in the drive you added, the old one. Check bott order and adjust accordingly. Then, after assuring you're booting correctly from the newly installed system, remove and repartition the old drive for other usages.

Comment: "Windows it said that it can't be installed on a non-GPT partition" - This means the WIndows installation environment was booted in UEFI mode while you selected a MBR partitioned disk. "My thought is that maybe my ASUS motherboard doesn't fully support Samsung SSD drive" - Doubtful. SATA is SATA.  The only expectation might be a specific SATA port might be enabled or disabled per the PCIe configuration.  Your manual would indicate if that is the case.

Comment: note, that motherboard has 3 different sets of SATA ports. 2 x Intel 6Gb, 2 x AsMedia 6Gb and 4 x Intel 3Gb

Comment: Hey ChanganAuto, Ramhound and Jaromanda. 

I've wiped everything with Parted Magic, reinstalled CMOS battery and installed the new Samsung SSD and changed the SATA cables to the white ports, so both SSD and HDD are connected to the white one and I've installed Fedora Workstation 37 on it. I'm writing on it right now without any issues.

I don't know what to say. Thank you goes without saying, a lot, as I was preparing to buy a new SSD. I think I might've connected it to the wrong SATA port I don't honestly know.

Thanks a bunch again!

Comment: Have you done anything like cloning disks and putting the source and target together on the PC? I had a problem regarding partition table signatures after a clone. I fixed it by doing this: 
1 - I cloned a small ssd to a bigger one.
2 - disconnect source and check if the target was okay.
3 - disconect target and reconnect source.
4 - Wipe source (new partition table) and format.
5 - Reconnect target, now source (new partition table) and target (cloned data) can work well together